# I Suspect My "Active Effects" in Skyrim are Showing but not Working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, pc

I suspect that some of the "Active Effects" shown for my character in Skyrim (PC - Steam) are listed, but not actually applying their benefits.

How can I check with the console - or otherwise - that an effect such as the exp. boost from a guardian stone is in fact, working?

Comment: Looking back, Im unsure what you expect from this outcome. If there is a console command to check if the effect is active, its only going to go as far as confirm the same thing confirmed by the icon being visible. It would require a lot more analysis to actually determine if it is working or not

Comment: @Timelord64 Well I figured that if the effect would show up in a console list it would confirm that the listing in "Active Effects" isn't just a ghost effect whose text was improperly removed when it should have ended. Also hence "or otherwise" I was wondering if anyone knew of a method where I can do a check for experience gains for that specific effect listed. i.e. x action grants 100 base exp; find out how many exact exp points it grants when i do it; find out if proper exp multipliers are active.

Comment: Save your game the perform some action and note how long it takes to level up that skill. Then reload the game and get rid of the guardian stone effect, repeat the action and note if it takes the same amount of actions (not working) or more actions to level the skill up (working).

Answer (score 1):

It *used* to be possible to directly query your experience progress with this command (you can replace smithing with [any of these things](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Actor_Value_Indices)):

```
player.getav SmithingSkillAdvance
```

In principle, you could save, do a bunch of smithing, check your skill advancement, load, deactivate the guardian stone, do the same amount of smithing as before, check your advancement again, and compare numbers.

As of patch 1.9, this [no longer works](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes5Mod:Actor_Value_Indices#SkillAdvance_Values), and a cursory examination of [the available commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) reveals no obvious alternatives.  But if you still have an older version of Skyrim for some reason, this method ought to work for you.  Otherwise, you'll have to eyeball it and/or smith enough to level up smithing.  Instead of eyeballing, you might try taking screenshots of the Skills screen and overlaying them with your image editor of choice.

**Having said all that**, in my (limited) modding experience, the Active Effects page is rarely or never incorrect.  If an effect does not get applied correctly, it's generally not visible in Active Effects, and I find that's the most reliable way of detecting these problems in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If the active affects are there, then they're working.

I don't believe there is a console command for checking if they are working, but you can look it over!

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check with the console - **or otherwise** [...]

In the case of the experience-boosting stone you mentioned: perform an action that grants experience towards one of the boosted skills, and measure the amount of experience gained per action, or equivalently the number of actions required to gain one entire level in that skill by performing only that action. Then load your game at the same point at which you began the previous experiment, remove the stone's boosting effect, and repeat the experiment.

Compare the number of actions required in both cases. If fewer actions are required in the boosted experiment, then the stone had an effect.